# Simplification of a logical expression for logic (laws of logic algebra)

Tags: math, boolean-logic, simplify

I am currently trying to learn how to simplify logical expressions. But I'm stuck on this problem where I have to simplify this expression using the laws of logic (Boolean algebra).I would like some help in simplifying the following expression:I'm not sure where to start simplifying. If anyone can describe where and what laws are used to simplify this expression, I would be very grateful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydilc.png)

Comment: I think this question would be better placed on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe replace the image with a formula. See https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

Comment: you could take a look at https://lamboolda.com/logic there are multiple options to simplify boolean-expressions for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Karnaugh map or just use simple algebra:
[image]